# IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF(can't find where is the error)

Tags: c#

I am trying to run my program in Visual Studio 2015. I created a `.mdf` database and a table in it. When I try to run it, I get this the following error:

```
cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table tblinfo when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF".
```

[image: Table]

[image: sql connection codes]

[image: Stored Procedure]

Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot insert into a column that has been defined as an `IDENTITY` column. The entire point of that is to let the server create the value for you.

Comment: @ShiranDror That's just a hack around the problem though, instead it's better to let the database create the value.

Comment: @KarmaKid, please, post code, not images where is possible

Comment: @DavidG setting IDENTITY_INSERT to ON is not a hack, it's an option. I've used it several times to move data from old to new databases

Comment: @ShiranDror As have I, but in this case it would be a hack to get the code working. Instead, OP should fix the code to not try and insert that value.

Answer (score 0):

Scope for "SET IDENTITY_INSERT" is based on the connection only. For the new connection, it will be reset.

Here, if you want to insert the data into the identity column, you have to set the  SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON in the stored procedure first before insert statement. Once data is inserted again set it to ON. SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF after the insert statement.

Comment: As pointed out in the comments above, this is a hack and probably shouldn't be recommended.

Comment: @Mittal, SET INDENTITY_INSERT ON|OFF is intended for bulk insert not for normal operation, although your code is possible, it's not recommendable. Whats happen in your code if the insert fails? The set indentity_insert off never happens

Comment: @mnieto, Agree with you, it is not recommended for the single insert. It should be used when we insert bulk data. Regarding the indentity_insert off, we can reset it in the try and catch block in a stored procedure.

Answer (score -1):

You should not insert your IDENTITY column. Instead, let SQL Server assign the value for you and return it back to your application code, with [scope_identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql)

```
create procedure dbo.addorupdate
...
begin
  if @node = 'add'
  begin
    insert into tblinfo (firstname, lastname, age, gender) values (@firstname, @lastname, @age, @gender)
    return scope_identity()
  end
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, it's a reasonable solution.